# Error with ImportXML within GoogleSheet

Tags: google-sheets, formula

To not use another thread and after trying to get my formula working with multiples examples from the Internet, I have built the following :

```
=importXML("http://www.sportingcharts.com/nhl/stats/player-blocks-statistics/2015/",  "//*[@id="statomatic"]/table")
```

However, when running it with Sheets, it gives me a parse error.
What have I done wrong ?

Comment: With web scraping tools I may have find a security system on this website that prevent the tool to get the table and its data. Is the parsing error a reflect of this anti-scrapping system ? I have not the skills to confirm that. Can anyone help me on this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Part 1: The parsing error

The parsing error occurs because the double quotes. Replace the inner double quotes by single quote. In other words, instead of

```
"//*[@id="statomatic"]/table"
```

something like the following should be used:

```
"//*[@id='statomatic']/table"
```

## Part 2: The xPath

Once the parsing error be resolved the resulting formula still will not work because the xPath can't be found.

The following xPath will return the stats table in the page:

```
"//div/table/*/tr"
```

Note: the quotes are included as they are required by the IMPORTXML formula.

Comment: Well I will test that right now. Thanks for the answer, I did lost hope about getting an answer :)

Comment: Well, the error have changed now, it is that the content is empty, so i have dig back on the logic I was using to find the table I was aiming at.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the reported error in the question was related to how double quotes was used. Anyway, are you sure that the xPath is correct?

Comment: Ruben, I did correct the quote and doing that provided me with another error (the content is empty). So yes I have to check the xPath. It seems taht since I'Ve posted the question, the webpage i'm trying to get the info from have change. I cannot find the id "statomatic" anymore. So I have to adapt the formula. But I least, thanks to you, I did not have the parsing error anymore.

Comment: And your Part 2 is fantastic. Thanks a lot. I was stuck with "=importXML("http://www.sportingcharts.com/nhl/stats/player-blocks-statistics/2015/", "//*/table")" getting the whole table in one cell. With your solution it is perfect. I can move on. THanks !